# Соединение Matlab с MySQL используя MariaDB (Windows 10)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, matlab

Мне не удается программно создать соединение из Matlab с MySQL используя MariaDB (драйвер ODBC).
В MySQL создана БД с таблицей, коннекция к ней проверена.
В Matlab настроены пути к папкам расположения библиотеки MariaDB: на закладке Home - setpath (к папкам lib и include).
Код:

```
datasource = "model1";
username = "root";
password = "qw.........";
tablename = "table1";
conn = mysql(datasource,username,password);
```

Ошибка в последнем операторе:

- Undefined function or variable 'mysql'.
  Error in Untitled (line 38)
  conn = mysql(datasource,username,password);

Функция mysql указана в примере на https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/mysql.html
Я посмотрел mysql.h - там нет описания функции mysql (есть mysql_real_connect со множеством параметров).
Пробовал подключать h-файл, ставил первым оператором
`coder.cinclude('<mysql.h>')`
. Не помогает.
Буду благодарен за подсказку, если у Вас есть опыт программного подключения из Matlab к MySQL (возможно другим способом, используя другие free-библиотеки).